# Can not do cross domain REST API Call from localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jira-rest-api

I am trying to do login using REST API provided by JIRA in REACT.
But I am getting error like

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:8085' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403. 
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Below is my code which I am testing to do sign on.

```
fetch("https://jira.company.com/rest/auth/latest/session",{
  method:'POST',
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"
  },
  body: 
    JSON.stringify({
    username:"username",
    password : "password"})
  }).then(result => console.log(result));
```

I have also tried with below parameter but it result with same error.

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS',
```

I have also looked into documentation for [JIRA API](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.6.1/) but can not find anything for cross domain request access.
Looking for help to do API call across domain.

Comment: The REST API isn't intended to be called from browsers (aka No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header). You can get at it from a server though, e.g. cURL. BTW the username/pwd is usually send in the header with `btoa`.

Comment: Thanks Ron, as those APIs are protected cannot be accessed through a browser. Is there any way to call protected API from a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by setting `mode: 'cors'`

```js
fetch("https://jira.company.com/rest/auth/latest/session", {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  },
  mode: 'cors',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    username: "username",
    password: "password"
  })
}).then(function(resp) {
  return resp.json();

}).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data)
});
```

Note:In the demo you may see `404` which mean not found because it is not sending username & password

Comment: I have tried it with mode:'cors' but it did not solve my problem. I have tried to do same API call using POSTMAN and it is working fine without providing mode in request.

Comment: are you still seeing 403?

Comment: Yes, still getting 403.

Comment: Getting "XSRF check failed" when I have checked request in chrome

Comment: that may be different from cors

Comment: @ParthPatel did it worked?